# how to build and bind custom exoplayer layout

Tags: java

I want to build an app that display movies through internet. and i want to use exoplayer to play the movies . I initialized the exoplayer and the exoplayer plays the url i passed to . But i want to change the layout of playback_controller and put my own layout but i dont know how to bind the custom layout with exoplayer.
i also dont how to set the progress bar,default time bar(or seek bar), and other buttons you will see in my layout.
these are my java code

```html
package com.example.novin.exoplayer;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Format;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.PlaybackParameters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Renderer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.RendererCapabilities;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Timeline;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.decoder.DecoderCounters;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorInput;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ts.TsPayloadReader;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectionArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelectorResult;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSpec;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.RawResourceDataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.VideoRendererEventListener;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import static com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    SimpleExoPlayerView playerView ;
    SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer ;
    Uri enternetUri= Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/training/images/tacoma_narrows.mp4");


    ImageButton btnPause , btnPlay;
    DefaultTimeBar seekBar ;



    RelativeLayout loadingBar ;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_exo);
        playerView= (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        playerView.setUseController(true);
        loadingBar= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loading_bar);
        btnPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        seekBar= (DefaultTimeBar) findViewById(R.id.exo_progress);











        try {

            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));

            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);


            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");

            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

            final MediaSource mediasource = new ExtractorMediaSource(enternetUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

            playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

            exoPlayer.prepare(mediasource);






            btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                }
            });

            btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                    btnPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MainActivity","exoplayer error" + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }


    public class ExoplayerClass implements ExoPlayer.EventListener {

        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

        }
    }



}
```

this is my exo_playback_control_view.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pro_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </RelativeLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/root">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:background="#96000000">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#f2ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:text="Video Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fefffe"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_cast"
            android:src="@drawable/chrom_cast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_time"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#96000000">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_current_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>

       <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
           android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:layout_width="400dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_total_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/cotrols"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#96000000">

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/lock2"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/btn_lock"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#fafcfa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/prev"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#f9fcf9"/>


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_rev"
                android:background="#f2f2f2"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/rewind"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>


            <ImageButton
                android:background="#f1e2e2"
                android:src="@drawable/play"
                android:id="@+id/btn_play"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:background="#0a0a0a"
                android:src="@drawable/pouse"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_forw"
                android:background="#f2f2f2"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/rewind"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/prev"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="#f9fcf9"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/subtitles"
            android:id="@+id/btn_sub"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:alpha="1"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_setting"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/setting"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Checkout this documentation
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0